# camel : File Poller of CSV

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to do File Poller of CSV, then unmarshaling.like this:

```xml
<route>
    <from uri="file:///some/path/to/pickup/csvfiles?delete=true&amp;consumer.delay=10000" />
        <unmarshal>
            <csv />
        </unmarshal>
    <to uri="bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData" />
</route>
```

But I also want to get also the file name in my bean. 
How do I do this ?

Comment: Same question posted on Camel user mailing list with answer how to do this - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/File-Poller-of-CSV-td5745296.html

Answer (score 0):

Have doHandleCsvData bind using the Exchange `doHandleCsvData(Exchange exchange)` then you can get the file name from the headers, extract the body and process the data.

Comment: Yes you can change it then do this `List<List<String>>csvData = exchange.getIn().getBody(List<List<String>>);` To get the data. Then to get the file name use `exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName");`

Comment: But my doHandleCsvData is like this: doHandleCsvData(List<List<String>> csvData) Can I just change it to doHandleCsvData(Exchange exchange) ? I will loose the unmarshal benefit , no ? Maybe I can do : <from uri="file:///some/path/to/pickup/csvfiles?delete=true&amp;consumer.delay=10000" /> <to uri="bean:myCsvHandler?method=process" /> <unmarshal><csv /></unmarshal> <to uri="bean:myCsvHandler?method=doHandleCsvData" /> and in process method get the file name , and then continue at doHandleCsvData? –  user3138101 36 mins ago